# How to update a reused variable using the same function without isolating it into another component?

Tags: reactjs

Let say we have this component, and we want to update the **`count` in Button 1** and the **`count` in Button 2** variable individually based on its previous value when clicking each button. Currently, both are updating when clicking either button.
Is there an efficient way to do this without isolating it in a new component?

```
function Foo() {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    function incrementCount(){
        setCount(count + 1)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            // Button 1
            <div>
                <p>count: {count}</p>
                <button onClick={incrementCount}>Click</button>
            </div>

            // Button 2
            <div>
                <p>count: {count}</p>
                <button onClick={incrementCount}>Click</button>
            </div>
             
        </div>
    )
}
export default Foo;
```

I do not want to do this:

```
function Foo() {

    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    function incrementCount(){
        setCount(count + 1)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            
            <div>
                <p>count: {count}</p>
                <button onClick={incrementCount}>Click</button>
            </div>
             
        </div>
    )
}
export default Foo;
```

Then calling 2 `Foo` components like this:

```
function AnotherComponent() {
    <Foo\>
    <Foo\>
}
export default AnotherComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use a dictionary to store each button state. This also works very well if you have a dynamic list of buttons.

In this example, the initialState already contains the properties for the buttons. But when rendering a dynamic list that is not always possible. To solve this, you can change the `incrementCount` function to deal with unset properties in the `count` variable.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Foo() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState({
      button1: 0,
      button2: 0
    });

    function incrementCount(event) {
        const name = event.currentTarget.name;
        setCount(current => ({ ...current, [name]: current[name] + 1 }));
    }
    
    return(
        <div>
            <div>
                <p>count: {count.button1}</p>
                <button onClick={incrementCount} name="button1">Click</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>count: {count.button2}</p>
                <button onClick={incrementCount} name="button2">Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Foo />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.14.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.14.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">App</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an array of `count` states, i.e. `counts`, and use the "index" to update the individual count states. This allows easy transition to simply mapping the `counts` state to JSX buttons.

```js
const Foo = () => {
  const [counts, setCounts] = React.useState(Array(2).fill(0));

  const incrementCount = (index) => () => {
    setCounts((counts) =>
      counts.map((count, i) => (i === index ? count + 1 : count))
    );
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {counts.map((count, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>count: {count}</p>
          <button onClick={incrementCount(index)}>Click</button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Foo />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```